# changing file iteratively in a bash loop

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a file default.txt which has this line

```
DEFAULT_CONFIG_PTH = models/config_100i.ini
```

and I need to change it in a loop

```
for m in $(seq 2 55); do
  sed 's/100i/i${m}/g' default.txt > tmp.txt
    mv tmp.txt default.txt
    run *.py # it uses default.txt
done
```

The problem is each time I change the file 100i changes to a new value say i2 I cannot change it in the next iteration to i3 as I need to replace i2 instead of 100i. Is there a way around this ?

Comment: `${m}` won't expand inside `'` single quotes. Use `"` double quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure. Copy the original file under a different name, say `template.txt`. Then do

```
sed '...' template.txt > default.txt
```

and you're done.

Another way is to fix the python script to accept a file name as the argument.